# Calculate $\lceil \frac{n}{log_2k} \rceil; n \geqslant 1, k \geqslant 2$ with only integer functions

Tags: logarithms, integer-programming

How to calculate following expression with only integer fuctions?
$$\lceil \frac{n}{log_2k}  \rceil; n \geqslant 1, k \geqslant 2$$

I mean with using of only integer division, [integer log with base of two](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious) and maybe other.

I am trying this formula, but it's not right for all cases:

$$(n - 1) \backslash IntLog2(k) + 1$$

Comment: Srry, this is irrelevant to your question, but I want to ask, do you use any software to type in Latex, or you type latex yourself?

Comment: @abstractnature, I typed in latex by myself with help of [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also I used [Detexify2 service](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) for getting '\' code in latex. Why did you ask about it?

Comment: oh ok, thnx, just a newcomer, i am having a lot of trouble typing in latex, for example I couldnt type, summation of Unions....